# Calling multiple values from data frame by row and column in R

Tags: arrays, r, matrix, dataframe

I'm working in R and I'd like to call a selection of values from a data frame by their column and row indices.  However doing this yields a matrix rather than an array.  I shall demonstrate:

Given the data.frame:

```
a = data.frame( a = array(c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9), c(3,3)) )
```

(for those of you who don't want to plug it in, it looks like this)

```
  a.1 a.2 a.3
1   1   4   7
2   2   5   8
3   3   6   9
```

And lets say I have two arrays pointing to the values I'd like to grab

```
grab_row = c(3,1,2)
grab_col = c(1,2,1)
```

Now I'd expect this to be the code I want...

```
a[ grab_row, grab_col ]
```

To get these results...

```
[1] 3 4 2
```

But that comes out as a 3x3 matrix, which makes enough sense in and of itself

```
  a.1 a.2 a.1.1
3   3   6     3
1   1   4     1
2   2   5     2
```

Alright, I also see my answer is in the diagonal of the 3x3 matrix... but I'd really rather stick to an array as the output.

Any thoughts?  Danka.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Passing the row and column indices in as a two-column matrix (here constructed using `cbind()`) will get you the elements you were expecting:

```
a[cbind(grab_row, grab_col)]
[1] 3 4 2
```

This form of indexing is documented in `?"["`:

> **Matrices and array:**
>
> [...snip...]
>
> A third form of indexing is via a numeric matrix with the one
>   column for each dimension: each row of the index matrix then
>    selects a single element of the array, and the result is a vector.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
> mapply(function(i,j)a[i,j], grab_row, grab_col)
[1] 3 4 2
```

Works for both dataframes and matrices.